# Octave - why is surf not working but trisurf does?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am able to plot a trisurf chart, but surf does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
pkg load statistics;
figure (1,'name','Matrix Map');
colormap('hot');
t = dlmread('C:\Map3D.csv');
tx =t(:,1);ty=t(:,2);tz=t(:,3);
tri = delaunay(tx,ty);
handle = surf(tx,ty,tz); #This does NOT work
#handle = trisurf(tri,tx,ty,tz);  #This does work
```

`error: surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and columns (Z) must be the same as length
 (X)

My data is in a CSV (commas not shown here)

```
1   2   -0.32
2   2   0.33
3   2   0.39
4   2   0.09
5   2   0.14
1   2.5 -0.19
2   2.5 0.13
3   2.5 0.15
4   2.5 0.24
5   2.5 0.33
1   3   0.06
2   3   0.44
3   3   0.36
4   3   0.45
5   3   0.51
1   3.5 0.72
2   3.5 0.79
3   3.5 0.98
4   3.5 0.47
5   3.5 0.55
1   4   0.61
2   4   0.13
3   4   0.44
4   4   0.47
5   4   0.58
1   4.5 0.85
```

Comment: The reason is clearly indicated in the error message: `surf` expects `x`, `y` as vectors (defining a Cartesian grid) and `z` as a matrix (data on that grid) with appropriate sizes. In your case those three arguments seem to be vectors (and probably are not grid-like).

Comment: I don't see anything about vectors or matrices! Are you looking at a different error message? Can you please show me how to cast to vector or matrix from what I have please.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking of one of the specific forms to call `surf`, namely `surf(vector_x, vector_y, matrix_z)`, but it can also be `surf(matrix_x, matrix_y, matrix_z)`. I suggest you take a look at the examples in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)

Comment: Actually, the reason I put this question on StackOverflow is because I couldn't understand the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

`surf` error message is different in Matlab or in Octave.

Error message from Matlab:

> Z must be a **matrix, not a scalar or vector**.

The problem is pretty clear here since you specified `Z` (for you `tz`) as a vector.

Error message from Octave:

> surface: rows (Z) must be the same as length (Y) and **columns (Z) must be the same as length (X)**

You are wrong here since on your example, columns (Z) = 1, but length (X) = 26, so here is the mistake.

One of the consequences of that is that with `surf` you cannot have "holes" or undefined points on your grid. On your case you have a X-grid from 1 to 5 and a Y-grid from 2 to 4.5 but point of coordinate (2, 4.5) is not defined.

---

@Luis Mendo, Matlab and Octave do allow the prototype `surf(matrix_x, matrix_y, matrix_z)` but the third argument `matrix_z` still have to be a matrix (not a scalar or vector). Apparently, a matrix of only one line or column is not considered as a matrix.

---

To solve the issue, I suggest something like:

```
tx = 1:5; % tx is a vector of length 5
ty = 2:0.5:4.5; % ty is a vector of length 6
tz = [-0.32 0.33 0.39 0.09 0.14;
      -0.19 0.13 0.15 0.24 0.33;
       0.06 0.44 0.36 0.45 0.51;
       0.72 0.79 0.98 0.47 0.55;
       0.61 0.13 0.44 0.47 0.58;
       0.85 0.   0.   0.   0.]; % tz is a matrix of size 6*5
surf(tx,ty,tz);
```

Note that I had to invent some values at the points where your grid was not defined, I put `0.` but you can change it with the value you prefer.

Comment: I am using octave, so how to I convert z to appropriate form please?

Comment: I really don't understand. I have 3 columns of x, y, z data. trisurf plots them easily. I don't understand what this tz matrix is or why I need to create it for surf!

Comment: Perhaps there is an octave function that creates an appropriate tz?

Comment: @ManInMoon the rules of surf say that tz needs to be a matrix not a vector. tz in my example is your tz I reordered so it becomes a matrix.

Comment: @ManInMoon yes maybe. Look closely, my first line is the first part of your vector etc...